# Who was allowed to enter the "Chamber of Guardians" on Oa?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, green-lantern-2011

In the *Green Lantern* movie, when Hal Jordan entered the *Chamber of Guardians* on Oa, Sinestro was angry with him, saying:

> You dare enter this chamber?

Who was allowed to enter that chamber? Is there a rank level at which a Lantern gains this privilege? Or, more specifically, are weaker and less intelligent species not allowed?

Only canonical answer, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In the DC Comics franchise, the Malthusians (now called the Guardians of Oa) are arguably, the oldest and wisest sentients in the known Universe. Their life forces have existed for billions of years and they have millions of years of recorded history stored within the Power Battery computer at the Center of Oa, their base of operations.**

- In any society where hierarchy is important, such as Sinestro's home world, access to the Guardians would be highly restricted and regulated by gatekeepers. The Guardians value propriety and structure and likely have a protocol for dealing with matters personally. Most interactions with Green Lanterns are done using their rings as a holo-interface.
- Given the Guardians prickly dispositions, it would be considered unusual for them to engage in personal interaction with Green Lanterns unless it was absolutely necessary. So while they may not require anyone to refrain from seeing them, they certainly won't stop anyone who limits interaction with them, such as Sinestro was doing. Sinestro was/is always considered to be the cream of the Green Lantern crop and could say and do things other Lanterns considered gospel.
- If you wonder if it is a matter of safety, the Guardians do not fear the Green Lanterns under their control. Their personal mastery of the Green Power makes them nearly immune to anything the average Green Lantern could muster against them. However, they have been written over the years from being weak as kittens without support from the Green Lantern Corps, to having powers capable of destroying worlds single-handedly.

Comment: Nice answer, but more clarification is needed: Sinestro was already in that chamber despite things of your 3 points. So, why couldn't Hal Jordan enter?

Comment: Sinestro is a well-established veteran, Hal Jordan is a newbie. That is all the difference Sinestro felt was necessary.